# Purged XDG from RPi 4 Raspbian Buster

Tags: installation, apt, raspberry-pi4, purge, raspbian-buster

I accidentally purged XDG from my Raspbian Buster using this command: `sudo apt purge -y xdg*`

I've installed XDG and any other components back few minutes after the deed, and I thought I fixed it but I didn't. Plus I didn't realize the mess I'd done and closed out the terminal after that, so I wasn't able to take a screenshot of the `apt` log.

I'd like to request someone to send me a screenshot of doing `sudo apt purge xdg*` then at the prompt section take a screenshot, and send it to me here please, so that I may try to install the additional packages removed during the purge.

I've tried to install all the packages listed under *Buster Full Packages* here too: https://gist.github.com/jarvisms/6d3edba4fc27829d5dfe7a2bd8c7c5fb

But I still couldn't: 1) bring back how Raspbian Buster was; 2) get other system components running again. Been searching for any hint for days but I think this issue's pretty unique (uniquely dumb lol)

I honestly like this version of RPi now, it's more convenient to use (albeit sadly less efficient due to constant CPU maxing out for some reason) than how it was out of the box. But I can't program in C++ or Python properly, and figuring that out might take me more than attempting this since I'm not really a Linux connoisseur.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This question should be made on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Noted, will migrate. Thanks.